# Python logging isn't work when running an exe

Tags: python, logging, pyinstaller

I am running a Service that points to my python exe (I used `pyinstaller` to generate the exe).

While this Service is running, Python logging is not logging anything into the log files.

However, when I run this from the command line, not using the exe - it logs everything just fine.

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: use an absolute path... i use logging with pyinstaller exes all the time

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ah, that did the trick! I was using a relative path (obviously). Thanks!